# Implementing SRP Challenge login system *with SSL* (Using PHP)

Tags: php, authentication

**My question:** Anyone knows how to implement `SRP` / `Diffie-Hellman` authentication in PHP (or if this has already been done)?

---

(Some details)

1. I'm using **CodeIgniter** with **TankAuth** (both latest version)
2. I'm **forcing SSL access** via .htaccess

One of the **requirements of this project** is to **use challenge-based authentication**, I read a lot about it, it seems that making `SRP` / `Diffie-Hellman` work with TankAuth (along with SSL) is a secure authentication solution (provided it's **properly** done!)

The only real problem is: I just couldn't translate the **[SRP specification](http://srp.stanford.edu/ndss.html#SECTION00032200000000000000)** into PHP/mysql (I thought I was good at math but obviously I'm *not*!)

It doesn't matter if it's plain php, I can adapt the code to make it work with CodeIgniter/TankAuth.

I googled a lot, the closest I could find is [this](http://unitstep.net/blog/2008/04/28/password-salting-and-the-modified-challenge-response-system/), but the implementation **just doesn't feel right**.

I also understand I'll eventually have to adapt this to make the two-steps authentication process look like a normal one-step standard login form (using ajax), but that's for later, right now I'm stuck with the logic.

Comment: Does that lockout things like OpenID, Shibboleth and other federated authentication protocols? When you say password-less, what does that mean in practice?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm not familiar with Shibboleth, but I can't use OpenID. Project specs specify that I have to use challenge-based authentication (I'm going to edit my post right away)

Comment: Have you looked around the [Openwall site](http://www.openwall.com/) (home of PHPass)? There's a lot of resources located there or linked through.

Comment: Thank you Jared, I'm going to read it, hopefully I'll find an answer to my question...

Comment: Are you or would you call this *Two-Factor Authentication*? Or is it somehow just different enough to not be two-factor? Because there's goes to be lots of two-factor setups, including one for CodeIgniter. What seems to be described doesn't factor in a physical second factor like an RSA key fob.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following here: what is that I may/may not call a Two-Factor Authentication? You mentionned Two-Factor Authentication for CodeIgniter, can you please share the name/link of the authentication library that implement this?

Comment: Google `codeigniter two factor authentication` There's more than a few, but the technical meaning of two factor is pretty specific and requires something like an external but owned thing like a biometric scan or calculated one-use number generator (like RSA sells). So what you're looking for may be "called" two-factor by the CI and PHP people for some reason, but I wonder if that's accurate.

Comment: Ahh OK, I'm afraid that's a no-no in this case. By `two steps` I meant this: server generates the challenge, client would respond, and finally server validates login.

Comment: Exactly. It's like a poor man's two-factor (because let's face it, most should not spend that kind of money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the SRP specs some time ago, and they nicely describe how to use some well known cryptographic building blocks and shape them into a zero-knowledge protocol. However, the cryptographic building block themselves are not explained (they are considered to be common knowledge for cryptographers).

If I understood correctly, SRP uses a mathematical scheme that can be proven to reduce to the Diffie-Hellman problem (my terminology is probably incorrect, I mean to say that the SRP problem can be proven to be at least as computationally expensive as the Diffie-Hellman problem) but it does not equal Diffie-Hellman.

Keep in mind that a [zero knowledge password scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) is considered to be one of the hardest things to implement correctly. I've written [an answer on SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546316/why-srp-is-not-plaintext-equivalent/4553193#4553193) some time ago. As you can see, it is significantly more complex than the 'Password salting and the modified Challenge-Response system'-implementation in the article you linked. (And you are correct in not trusting it, I think I can spot weaknesses in it, and I'm only a security enthusiast, not a cryptographer or security professional).

In addition to the above, SRP is, as far as I know, a copyrighted scheme.

So my advice would be: stick with the current best practice of using a strong hashing algorithm (BCrypt)  on the server side secure your communication channel with TLS (SSL), instead of implementing a very complex scheme such as SRP.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm was ported to JavaScript for clients (browsers) and to PHP for servers: See [Ruslan Zavacky's spr-6a-demo](https://github.com/RuslanZavacky/srp-6a-demo) on GitHub.